# Consumir WebService WCF

Tags: c#, angular, wcf, http-post

Desarrollé un servicio con C# que consulto una base de datos con ciertas funciones.

Pasé de AngularJS a Angular2 y aquí vinieron mis problemas.

Dentro de mi WCF tengo :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetCaptaciones", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json , BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
List<Captacion> GetCaptaciones(int id_captador)
```

Desde Angular2 estoy haciendo la llamada a este método así:

```
let data = JSON.stringify({ id_captador: 11 });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post(url + "/GetCaptaciones", data, options).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Pero recibo el error de que los datos de entrada no son correctos. Recibe datos `Raw` mientras que los datos que espera son `JSON`. Sin embargo si yo en Postman copio el `JSON` y lo envío funciona todo correctamente.

Datos de pestaña NetWork

Response Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:POST
Cache-Control:private
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 27 Apr 2017 21:45:34 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

Request Header

```
Accept:'*/*'
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:XXXXXXX
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Intenta cambiando `let data = JSON.stringify({ id_captador: 11 });` por `let data = { id_captador: 11 };`

Comment: Haz una prueba cambiando la forma en que creas los `headers`, intenta usar `let headers = new Headers(); headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Comment: Hola, ninguna de las dos formas consigue que se solucione

Comment: si invocas el servicio de wcf usando [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), resuelve correctamente ?

Comment: Si, todo bien desde postman @LeandroTuttini

Comment: Revisaste el Developer Tools del browser (al cual accedes con F12, en la solapa Network) cuando invocas el servicio a que url esta queriendo acceder y que datos envia en el post del Request

Comment: Lo revise, pero no lo q me dices le echo una mirada y te cuento altiro @LeandroTuttini

Comment: La idea es que si la invocacion falla deberias poder ver el error http que recibes, quizas no sea un tema de invocacion sino de seguridad, eso lo sabras cuando veas que codigo http recibe la invocacion. Ademas si puede quita el "_" del nombre del parametro puede traer problemas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57864/discussion-between-sioesi-and-leandro-tuttini).

Comment: @LeandroTuttini edite mi pregunta con los datos que me pedias

Comment: Sería posible que nos postearas el contenido de la petición y de la respuesta? Es decir, que es exactamente el contenido que se está enviando al servicio y que es exactamente lo que el servicio está respondiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que

```
List<Captacion> GetCaptaciones(int id_captador)
```

espera un int y no un objeto que es lo que envías en el json,
intenta a enviar el 11 directamente.

Comment: Y si intentas lo contrario, es decir, que el método acepte un objeto: List<Captacion> GetCaptaciones(MyObject o)